# alutLoadMemoryFromFile invocation error

Tags: c#, alu, tao-framework

This is part of a function that loads sound for my sprite game made in C# and Tao.

```
int format;
float frequency;
int size;    
IntPtr data = Alut.alutLoadMemoryFromFile(path, out format, out size, out frequency);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(data != IntPtr.Zero, "alutLoadMemoryFromFile failed.");
```

On my PC this Assert is fine. I gave my game to few people and on their computers this Assert fails. What could possibly be the reason?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check whether the path is valid:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(File.Exists(Path), "File not found");
```

Comment: I have that check before yes, everything fine. Something else must be the problem.